# Filter tableView using custom search textField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hello friends In one of my activity I have created custom text field and I have array which have 50 records  and create custom table for load array records....now i want when we type in text field then my array records should be filter and get desire record in table view...

```
UITextField *patientname=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,10,170,30)];
patientname.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
patientname.tag=1;
//the horizontal alignment of the text
patientname.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
patientname.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
patientname.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
patientname.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
patientname.delegate =self;
[Self.view addSubview:patientname];
```

This is my array ...

```
Array Name (
"Mr. Ram  Singh",
"Mr.   ",
"Master DSHKJLKD  null mfkmlkdfsg",
"Mr. Rajat  Jain",
"Mrs. Sonali K Singh",
"Mr. Amit  Singh",
"Mr. Paan  Singh",
"Mr. Ajit  Singh",
"Dr. Rohan  Sharma",
"Mr. Arpita  Tripathi",
"Mr. Jacky  Chain",
"Ms. Malini  Ramani",
"Mr. Ankit  Chavan",
"Mr. Ankit  Gupta",
"Ms. Ragini  Khanna",
"Mr. Raj  Kumar",
"Mr. Manish  gupta",
"Mr. Anshul  Aggarwal",
"Ms. Priya  Ranjith",
"Mr. Sdf Sdf Sdf",
"Mr. Sanyam  Jain",
"Mr. Rakesh  Gupta",
"Mr. Vishnu  Gupta",
"Mr. Shabbir K Malik",
"Mr. mohan  gupta",
"Mr. Sajat  Jain",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. ravi  kapoor",
"Miss Mona  Hdjdbshs",
"Mr. test new  demo",
"Mr. Devdas  Gupta",
"Mr. Tarun  Malik",
"Mr. Mayank  Sharma",
"Miss Rachits  Guptas",
"Mr. Test T Patient",
"Mr. Manish  Kumar",
"Mr. Asd Asd Asd",
"Mr. NARENDRA  Garg",
"Mr. ritik  gupta",
"Mr. Mohd  Salim",
"Mr. Anshul  Garg",
"Ms. tanvi  anand",
"Mr. ashish  singh",
"Mr. Navdeep  Bora",
"Mr. Rajat  Kumar",
"Mr. shardul  negi",
"Mr. Shrey  Bhalla",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Dushyant  Sharma",
"Mr. Ritesh  Kapoor",
"Mr. Jamna  Das",
"Mr. hello  patient",
"Mr. Ashish  Vashisht",
"Ms. Prachi  Pant",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Sunil Kumar Singh",
"Mr. Mohd  Ali",
"Mr. Jay  Singh",
"Mr. Pantient  Patient",
"Mr. paitent  demo",
"Mr. adi  df",
"Mr. Anamika  Gupta",
"Mr. Subh  Karmakar",
"Mrs. Kirshna  Kumar",
"Mr. Jay  Kishan",
"Mr. Ram  Singh",
"Mr. Jagjeet  Singh",
"Mr. Badal  Yadav",
"Mr. Isha  Bhalla",
"Mr. Saadhna  Gupta",
"Mr. Tar  Un",
"Mr. SR  Khan",
"Mr. amar  nath",
"Mr. ankur  kaul",
"Mr. Qwe Qwe Qwe",
"Ms. Fgh Fgh Fgh",
"Mr. Kishan  Lal",
"Mrs. Kkkk Kkk Kkk",
"Mr. radha  gupta",
"Mrs. Meena  Sharma",
"Mr. Charu  Jain",
"Mr. dsf  df",
"Mr. Testdemo  Demotest",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Yogendra  Singh",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. rachit  Gupta",
"Mr. Raman  Malhotra",
"Mr. American  Jain",
"Mr. aakash  gandhi",
"Mr. Mohd  Ali",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Arpit  Gupta",
"Mr. nitish  Kumar",
"Mr. Drupad  Jain",
"Mr. Ashish  Moza",
"Mr. Rajat  Jain",
"Mr. Shan  Kumar",
"Mrs. Mahinder  Kapoor",
"Mr.   ",
"Ms. megha  priya",
"Ms. lata  gupta",
"Mr. Test  Patientb",
"Dr. Himanshu Kumar Parashar",
"Mr. Gfh  Gfh",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. ZX  Zxc",
"Ms. manvi  mehra",
"Mr. ramesh  Babu",
"Mr. Dushyant Kumar Sharma",
"Mr. Asd Asd Asd",
"Mr. Rachit  Gupta",
"Mr. Sachin  Kumar",
"Mr. Rakesh  Sharma",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Amit  Kumar",
"Mr. Ram Kumar Naresh",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. John Kumar Cena",
"Mr. sahd  df",
"Mr. Asdfasd Asf Qweqwe",
"Mr. Sanjeev  Kumar",
"Mr. Geeta  Sharma",
"Mr. Ram  Kumar",
"Mr. Sunil  Rai",
"Mr. atul  gupta",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. martin  luther",
"Mr. Asd Qwe Qwe",
"Mr. Test  Kumar",
"Mr. Shrey  Bhalla",
"Miss Neha  Jain",
"Ms. Anushka  Sharma",
"Miss Jaysheer  Jain",
"Mr. Fhdf Bgjgh ",
"Mr. Deepak  Gupta",
"Mr. Test  Patienta",
"Mr. Subh  Karmakar",
"Mr. Mohan  Kumar",
"Mr. apoorv  sharma",
"Mr. ankit  rathor",
"Mr. tarun  gupta",
"Mr. Mohd  Rizwan",
"Mr. hello  sd",
"Mr. Amit  Gupta",
"Mr. Dushyant 2nd  Sharma",
"Mr. anshul  aggarwal",
"Mr. Asd Asd Asd",
"Mr. Jitesh  Kumar",
"Mr. Hodor Hodor Hodor",
"Mr. Abhinav  Goel",
"Mr. Testz Z Patietn",
"Mr. Mohit  Dani",
"Mr.   ",
"Mr. Jinender  Jain",
"Mr. aditya  rai",
"Mr. Ankit Kjhk Loonia",
"Master Himanshu  Kumar",
"Mr. mohan  bhargav",
"Mr. Mohan  Kumar",
"Mr. Satypal  Kapoor",
"Mr. Mohit  Raina",
"Mr. Asd Qwe Qwe",
"Mr. test  test",
"Mr. Garima  Gupta",
"Mr. Mayank  Jain",
"Mr. Test  C"
```

)
This data load in a custom table like as....

```
 table_SearchPatient=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,40,170,250)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
table_SearchPatient.delegate=self;
table_SearchPatient.dataSource=self;
table_SearchPatient.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
table_SearchPatient.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
[self.view addSubview:table_SearchPatient];
```

this table load all data successfully and how to search required name use custom text field ....please solve  problem..

Answer (score 2):

Implement UITextFieldDelegate and the method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

In this method, when you write on your textfield, you can search text in your array and fill a filtered array. Then you reload your table with reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way::

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                addObserver:self 
                   selector:@selector(anyMethod:)
                       name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
                     object:textField1];
```

on change text Method (here "anyMethod:") get the textfield text and get records that matches with textfield text and save it in another array. and then load data with that filtered array. so that it will look like text filter in tableview.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add observer to get text change notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(textFieldDidChangeText:)
                   name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
                 object:textField];
```

Then implement the text change notification method as given,

```
-(void)textFieldDidChangeText:(id)sender {

NSString *text = [sender text];

tableViewDataSrcArray = [dataSrcArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", text]];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Assume 'dataSrcArray' is your actual list and 'tableViewDataSrcArray' is your table view data source array.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: when we use this line tableViewDataSrcArray = [dataSrcArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contains[cd] '%@'", text]]; then it shows
assigning to nsmutablearray from incompatible type void                   please help me...

Comment: I made a small change in the code. Please take it, try and let me know if any errors occurred..

Comment: when we use tableViewDataSrcArray and dataSrcArray both array then show assigning to nsmutablearray from incompatible type void...so i don't know what the the problem

Comment: It is because your tableViewDataSrcArray is mutable. If you want to keep it as mutable itself, then you have to create a mutable filtered list as given, tableViewDataSrcArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataSrcArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", text]]];

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you are using search bar, create a temp array from table array. and use following method

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
        tableDataArray  = tempArray;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = TRUE;
        NSMutableArray *searchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:friendsArray];
        NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@",text];
        tableDataArray  =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}
```